# Visual Studio Project Installer not installing all dll's

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I have a C# exe, called 'start.exe' that is when run will check a SQL database and copy a file to a folder if certain criteria are met.

This works on most computers.

But on some computers when I try to run it I get the following error message.

```
System.invalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' is not registered on the local machine
```

To fix this I created a setup project that should add the missing .dll.

I created the set up project, went to the applications folder, added the primary output of the project.

I then ran a batch build on all the files and copied the msi and setup .exe files to a problem computer and ran it.

It adds System.Net.Http.dll and 'start.exe' to the computer.

When I run the exe, it still gives me the same error.

I believe the message box comes from these lines of code.

```
try            
{
     using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + CurFeSource + ";"))
     {
         conn.Open();

         using (var cmdBE = new OleDbCommand("SELECT value FROM Tab1", conn))
         {
             OleDbDataReader rdrBE = cmdBE.ExecuteReader();

             rdrBE.Read();

             be_version = (rdrBE.GetString(0));

             rdrBE.Close();
          }

          using (var cmdFE = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Col FROM Links", conn))
          {
             OleDbDataReader rdrFE = cmdFE.ExecuteReader();

             rdrFE.Read();

             fe_version = (rdrFE.GetString(0));

             rdrFE.Close();
           }
       }
   }

   catch (Exception e)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
       return false;
   }
```

Edit:

As SQLGeorge said, I need to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.

But how do I add it to a setup project.

Comment: https://www.layer2solutions.com/support/business-data-list-connector-faqs/how-to-access-office-2010-data-from-sharepoint

Comment: That DLL is not part of your solution. It is part of MS Access (runtime) so you need to either install Access or at least install the runtime you can download from Microsoft. See the answer of @SQLGeorge

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 must be downloaded from Microsoft: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Excerpt From Microsoft:

> This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and **Microsoft Office Excel 2010** (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text files is also supported. ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats.

As noted by Microsoft:

> As a general replacement for Jet (If you need a general replacement for Jet you should use [SQL Server Express Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express)).